# May have broken a Debian installation: 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' won't run

Tags: debian, linux-kernel, kernel-panic

I did an `apt-get upgrade` on my Jessie vps, hosted by DigitalOcean. As many people know, DigitalOcean provides kernels from the host, rather than allowing the VM to boot from its own kernel image. Thankfully there is a workaround using kexec to reboot, loading a newer, more up-to-date kernel if DO falls behind on security fixes.

Now, I cannot get `dpkg` to configure libselinux1:amd64. An update for it was put out, but `dpkg` just causes a kernel panic. This happened originally on my `apt-get upgrade`, and now it's happening when I run `dpkg --configure -a`. I'm not sure what to do at this point. Any tips would be helpful.

I'm running the 3.10.11 Jessie kernel through kexec, but when the VM first boots, it boots from a 3.11.5 Sid kernel supplied by DigitalOcean because for some reason in their kernel management they only have Stable and Unstable and no 64-bit Testing kernels. Go figure.

```
init: log.c:861: Assertion failed in log_serialise: log->io
init: Caught abort, core dumped
Kernel panic - not syncing: Attempted to kill init! exitcode=0x00000600
```

The install still works, I'm just unable to update any packages until this is fixed.

Comment: If the kernel is crashing, this is a bug in the kernel (or in the hardware). Complain to the kernel provider, i.e. DigitalOcean.

Comment: You're running a production website on a kernel from Sid? That seems sketchy at best. (I realize you're not quite _running_ it, but you're still using it.)

Comment: Running it on a kernel from Testing, not Sid.